# Delete XML information using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

So currently I am able to save 1-9 AS3 variables depending on what the user wants, they are saved as text strings into an XML file however when the user saves again the old xml information remains in the file and the new information is added.
However I want the new information to either write over the old information or set a function to clear/delete the information in the xml file before the new settings are saved.

Here is my current save function:

```
var soundVAR;
var conditionVAR;
var soundtoXML:XML; 
var conditiontoXML:XML; 
var test = 1;
var playingCounter = 0;
var xml:XML = <saved>
        </saved>;


//1.Button event listener
btn_Save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, saveXML);
//2.The saveurl function which opens a URL.
function saveXML(event:MouseEvent):void {


var conditionsArray = new Array(play1Condition, play2Condition, play3Condition, play4Condition, play5Condition, play6Condition, play7Condition, play8Condition, play9Condition)

for (var i=0; i < conditionsArray.length; i++){
trace(conditionsArray[i])
if(conditionsArray[i] == true)
{
    soundVAR = soundsName[i];
    conditionVAR = conditionsArray[i];


    playingCounter++;    
} else {

    trace('no sounds are playing');
}

while (xml.item.length() < playingCounter ){
    var soundString:String =  '<sound>' + soundVAR + '</sound>';
    var conditionString:String = '<condition>' + conditionVAR + '</condition>';
    soundtoXML = new XML(soundString);
    conditiontoXML = new XML(conditionString);

    var item:XML = <item />
    item.@id = xml.item.length().toString();
    xml.appendChild(item);

    var sound:XML = xml.item[xml.item.length() - 1];
    var condition:XML = xml.item[xml.item.length() - 1];
    sound.appendChild(soundtoXML);
    condition.appendChild(conditiontoXML);
}
}
writeXML();
trace(xml);
}

function writeXML(){

var savedSounds:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal( 'savedSounds');
savedSounds.data.soundsxml = xml; // your variables
savedSounds.flush(); // stores data into disk


}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I have no idea why your question was downvoted, since the person responsible didn't comment. I didn't think the downvote was appropriate, so I upvoted.

Comment: Thanks man, I was a bit confused about that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you want to call `xml.item.setChildern('');` before the `while` loop. Longer answer: I don't understand the last 4 lines of the while loop. Can you explain what was the intent behind writing them?

If I understood your code correctly, then the while loop could look like so:

```
var i:int = xml.item.length();
while (i < playingCounter)
{
    xml.* += <item id={ i }>
          <sound>{ soundVAR }</sound>
      <condition>{ conditionVAR }</condition>
    </item>;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: First I would like to say thanks for the help.
The application is a sound mixer where the nine variables are different sounds, and the <sound> stores the variable names and <condition> stores the boolean true or false depending if the sound has been selected or not.
Your code looks good, so in theory this would clear the information in the xml just before it is written using the setChildren function?

Comment: I don't have access to the flash file now but i'll reply tomorrow and let you know if i got it working, thanks

Comment: using the `delete` operator should work, much the same as how you'd use it to delete a property from an `Object` - `delete xml.item.whatever;`

Comment: Thanks divily, that could also have worked. I ended up going with the set Children function and it worked fine.